# How to type the letter "i" with two dots (diaeresis) in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents, characters

I would like to type the letter "i" in math mode, but with two (horizontally aligned) dots rather than with just one.

I know there is `\ddot{i}`, but that puts the two dots *on top* of the existing one, while `\text{\"i}` sets the letter in text form rather than in math mode. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) = \ddot i \\
  f(x) = \text{\"i}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

How can I get the desired result? Thanks! (And I know that the two dots can lead to confusion with the second derivative.)

Comment: `\ddot{\imath}`

Comment: @egreg Fast, concise and precisely what I needed - thank you! Do you want to turn it into an answer for acceptance? Couldn't get any better anyway, I guess...

Comment: The same applies to `\jmath`.

Comment: Um - should I leave or delete this question now, since I apparently overlooked the question @egreg pointed out? Should I accept Bernard's answer given below? Or should I wait for egreg to turn his comment into answer, since he was "first"?

Comment: @Bernd Leave it; it can be useful also if closed as duplicate.

Comment: Don't delete it -- duplicate questions are useful for searching because they describe the same problem, but use different wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\ddot{\imath}` for mathitalic – or `\ddot{\i}` for mathroman.